# Is it safe to purge %WinDir%\assembly\NativeImages*\Temp\?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, dotnet-framework

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 (SBS 2011) i have found more than 25 GB of files that *seem* to be junk:

```
%WinDir%\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Temp\ - 6.9 GB (656 files in 675 folders)
%WinDir%\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Temp\ - 18.5 GB (1174 files in 1198 folders)
%WinDir%\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Temp\ - 0 GB (0 files in 0 folders)
%WinDir%\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Temp\ - 0 GB (0 files in 0 folders)
```

Best visualized with helper utilities such as `TreeSize` (by JAM Software) or `WinDirStat`.

**Main Question:**
Is it safe to manually delete the `%WinDir%\assembly\NativeImages*\Temp\` folders?

**Bonus Question:**
Is it normal to have such a lot of data in those temp folders?
In the "v2.0" folders i have *several GB*! But in the "v4.0" folders I have *0 bytes*.
So I assume that something must have gone wrong with the built-in mechanisms of `ngen.exe` or `mscorsvw.exe` to clean the v2.0 "Temp" folders.
I have tried the usual maintenance tasks (with Windows `Disk Cleanup` etc.), but it still did *not* free anything in those temp folders.

--

PS:
The related question [Is purging %SYSTEMROOT%\assembly\temp safe?](https://serverfault.com/q/619689/292006) is about:
 - `%WinDir%\assembly\temp\`
but here I'm asking about:
 - `%WinDir%\assembly\NativeImages*\Temp\`

Comment: Yes, it's normal for them to be huge. You may want to try using the File cleanup tool from Microsoft. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17421/windows-free-up-drive-space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it certainly isn't normal behaviour. something must have gone wrong.
i have checked multiple machines. including different windows versions. most of them do *not* show these symptoms.

after doing some more searching i ran across a discussion thread (in german language) here: http://www.mcseboard.de/topic/210325-exchange-m%C3%BCllt-c-zu/

there the OP mentions a particular **antivirus software** by "g data".
and yes, on all of *my* machines that are showing these symptoms i have also installed this antivirus software. either the personal edition "g data antivirus 25.3.0.3" or the "business" edition "14.0.1.122".

so far i have confirmed this symptom on: windows 7, windows 10, windows 2008 r2.
i have also tested and reproduced the symptom on a "clean" machine: the temp folders are empty. then i installed this antivirus software. once i install some updates for the .net framework it is now leaking files in the NativeImages temp folders.

i had opened a support ticket with the vendor.
the support team has **confirmed** they already know about this issue and that **they're working on a fix** for both, the business and the personal edition of their antivirus software.
they have not come back with a clear answer weather it's safe to manually delete the leaked files.

anyways, i have manually emptied those folders and have **not** faced any issues so far.

Comment: How is the support ticket progressing? Can you share a link where we can follow along? I just manually deleted 60 gigs of mentioned temp folders. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe to delete the contents of this folder, it's used for the .NET Global Assembly Cache (GAC). I would leave the folder itself alone, just delete the contents. Worse thing that could happen is .NET breaks, and a reinstall of it should resolve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely delete the temp folders as long as you leave your assembly directory intact:

```
rmdir c:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Temp\ /s /q

rmdir c:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Temp\ /s /q
```

Then remove G-Data from your computer, reboot

Now you can create your nativeimages with:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe update
```

No ZapXXX directories should exist now.

Reinstall G-Data, reboot

You should be safe until the next .NET update, where it all begins unless there is a fix from G-Data

Answer (score 0):

Received Version 14.0.1.124 of EndpointProtection Enterprise today after I opened a ticket with G-Data. It seems this version fixes the problem, I could not reproduce it on two different systems anymore